# Under what conditions will PDO:execute() return false?

Tags: php, exception, pdo

According to http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php, it returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.

What constitutes success or failure?

I've tested it and returning an empty set or not inserting a row due to the WHERE clause does not.

Will it only do so given invalid SQL?  If so, wouldn't this throw an exception as well?

Comment: It returns false when there is an error. It might happen improper parameters, due to lack of connection,etc..

Comment: @JayBlanchard  I `try` it and have a `catch` block if the query doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will return `false` on any query that could not be executed successfully. Reasons for this may include a disconnected database, query syntax errors, you trying to call undefined SQL functions and such. An empty result set is not a failure.

Comment: Will all of these conditions also throw an exception?  Reason I ask is I have a `try` `catch` block which will roll back any changes.  Do I need to test what it returns, or will the `catch` block also be executed?

Comment: You need to explicitly set PDO to throw exceptions. By default it does not. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php If you've done so, `execute()` should throw exceptions instead of returning `false`.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  I've always included `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` when creating my connection, and I've never seen them not throwing exceptions.  Is it okay to rely on the exception, or should it also be tested and manually throw an exception upon no success?

Comment: Exceptions should be perfectly reliable.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Error, connection drop etc... when you dont have throw exceptions enabled.

Comment: And when throw exceptions are enabled, never?

Comment: correct, before it can return false it will throw a PDOException

Comment: It might also return false if there were parameters listed in the query but none supplied in the execute

Comment: But your latest example will also throw and exception, true?

Comment: Yeah it will throw an exception PARAMS_NOT_BOUND or something.